# set background image to relative layout in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I set background image to the relative layout in `xamarin.forms` portable project?

I have tried the following code:

**Xamal file**:

```
 <RelativeLayout x:Name="Title">
    <Label Text="Hello Xamarin"
        TextColor="Black"
        FontSize="22"
        FontFamily="Tahoma"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width, Factor=0.03}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Factor=0, Property=Y}"
     />
```

**xaml.cs file**:

```
public partial class MainApp : ContentPage
{

    public Image BGImage { get; set; }
    public MainApp()
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = "/Images/landing_page.jpg";
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a image view to the relative layout, please see the following link;

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17794/image-as-background

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add background image in XAML file for the entire page in Xamarin project, then use BackgroundImage property.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhoneDailerDemo"
             x:Class="PhoneDailerDemo.MainPage"
             BackgroundImage="image3.jpg">

    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <StackLayout Padding="100">
       //..........
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This works for me but the image distorts to be in-proportionate. How to set image to center and fill?